# Diff between Top 5 and 5 Top

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

What is the difference between `Top 5 something` and `5 Top something`. Is there really any difference or are both the same.

Comment: I think **5 top** works better for the more general case - *the two biggest men* could probably always replace *the biggest two men*, but to me at least, *"I couldn't answer the hardest two questions"* sounds a bit "back-to-front".

Answer (score 3):

> (The) top five swimmers competed today
>
> Five top swimmers competed today

There is a difference. The first means that the five swimmers were the absolutely highest ranking swimmers in the competition. The second means merely that five highly ranking swimmers competed, and they could've been the third, fourth, fifth, ninth and even fiftieth, depending on how flattering you're trying to be.